# Proof that a function is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Prove that the binary function is not surjective in the variable $x_{3}$.

$f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})=\overline{x_{1}}$, where $\{x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\}\in X=\{0,1\}$

Please, answer in detail!

I tried to do this, but I don't really understand what it gives to solve the problem.

[image: Function]

Comment: What does $\;\overline{x_1}\;$ mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio if $x_{1}$ is $1$, $\overline{x_{1}} = 0$, and if $x_{1}$ is $0$, $\overline{x_{1}} = 1$

Comment: that's not a binary operation; it's a trinary operation.  ANd it *is* surjective;  for every $a\in \{0,1\}$ there are $x_1,x_2,x_3$ so that $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = a$.  So ... it's hard to understand or answer this question.

Comment: What does "surjective on a variable" mean?

Comment: @fleablood binary function means that $X=\{0,1\}$

Comment: Sorry, was confusing it with binary operation.  What we call a function with a specific codomain is not really relevent.  But again:  What does "surjective in a variable" mean? and $f$ *IS* surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand 'surjective in one variable' in the following sense:

*If you fixate $x_1$ and $x_2$ you'll get a map $$f_{x_1,x_2}:X\to X: x \mapsto f(x_1,x_2,x)$$
Now $f$ is called surjective in $x_3$ if there are $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that the map $f_{x_1,x_2}$ is surjective.*

If that's what you mean by 'surjective in one variable' we need to show the opposite. That there are no $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f_{x_1,x_2}$ is surjective. This is easy by looking at the given table (the choices of $x_1$ and $x_2$ won't matter since you are only varying $x_3$ but the map $f$ only depends on $x_1$).

Comment: why do you say it's not surjective?  If you need to solve $f(x,y,z) = 0$ we have four solutions (any $(x,y,1)$).  And if we need to solve $f(x,y,z) =1$ we have four solutions (any $(x,y,0)$).  Of for any $a \in \{0,1\}$ there will exist $(x,y,z)$ so that $f(x,y,z) = a$.  So $f$ is *CERTAINLY* surjective.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, f is certainly surjective but the map $f_{x_1,x_2}$ is not. Suppose we pick $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = 0$. Then $f_{x_1,x_2}(0) = f(x_1,x_2,0) = f(0,0,0) = 1$ and $f_{x_1,x_2}(1) = f(0,0,1) = 1$. Therefore the map $f_{x_1,x_2}$ isn't surjective. You can check that this doesn't depend on the choices of $x_1$ and $x_2$ - the map $f_{x_1,x_2}$ won't be surjective. Since it was asked for 'not surjective in the variable $x_3$' I guessed that every other variable (i.e. $x_1$ and $x_2$) should be considered fixated. So we need to look at the map $f_{x_1,x_2}$ and not at $f$.

Comment: @PhilippOtto  That's very weird...even if it was true (with an also rather weird definition of "surjective in some variable"), the question asked about $\;f\;$ , *not* about that $\;f_x\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't see the problem. Why is this definition of 'surjective in one variable' weird? It's the sensible one for this problem. The answer is about $f$ since it doesn't matter which $x_1$ and $x_2$ you choose.

Comment: @PhilippOtto I don't agree with both your claims: 1) that "surjective in one varialbe" thing is not a standard one and it should then be properly defined by the OP, not by you, and 2) you yourself said $\;f\;$ is surjective but $\;f_{x_1, x_2}\;$ is not", and that shows your claim applies to the last one but not  to the former one, which is what the OP wrote and meant

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes I agree, OP should clarify what 'surjective in one variable' means. In the meantime I gave an answer using the definition I suspected. I edited the original answer to clarify this. The answer also better explains my suspected definition so that there is no misunderstanding why I look at $f_{x_1,x_2}$ instead of $f$. I hope that resolves the issue? Thanks for pointing these things out.